# Is there a way to throw an exception in a return statement that uses the ternary operator?

Tags: java, return, conditional-operator

I have a function that returns null in some cases, such as:

```
public Class Foo {
    public static Double bar(double a, double b) {
        if (a == 0 || b == 0) return null;
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

And I want to make another function that does exactly the same thing except it throws an error instead of returning null if that condition is met. I tried doing this:

```
public Class Foo {

    public static Double bar(double a, double b) {
        if (a == 0 || b == 0) return null;
        return a + b;
    }

    public static Double barWithException(double a, double b) {
        return bar(a, b) == null ? throw new IllegalArgumentException() : bar(a, b);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately Java doesn't like this and gives me a syntax error on the "throw" token (and tells me it can't convert from IllegalArgumentException to Double). The only other way I can think to do this would be like this:

```
public Class Foo {
    
        public static Double bar(double a, double b) {
            if (a == 0 || b == 0) return null;
            return a + b;
        }
    
        public static Double barWithException(double a, double b) {
            if (bar(a, b) == null) throw new IllegalArugmentException();
            return bar(a, b);
        }
    
    }
```

Which is of course totally fine, I was just wondering if there was a way to do this in one line or integrate exception throwing into the conditional operator. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Optional` for this

```
return Optional.ofNullable(bar(a, b))
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException());
```

Comment: Saying that this 'fits on one line' is a bit of a stretch. Especially considering that in real code the IAEx constructor invocation also needs a bunch of text.